# XSLT: changing a color based on a condition

Tags: html, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Consider the following xml document:

```
    <list>
    <group name="pilots">
        <person nat="france" gender="female">
            <name>mark webber</name>
            <address>911 somewhere circle, canberra, australia</address>
            <team>redbull</team>
        </person>
        <person nat="poland">
            <name>robert kubica</name>
            <address>121 zootle road, cape town, south africa</address>
        </person>
    </group>
    <group name="rugby">
        <person nat="france">
            <name>thomas castaignede</name>
            <adresse>30 rue de la paix, mont-de-marsan, france</adresse>
        </person>
        <person nat="uk">
            <name>shane williams</name>
            <address>113 best lane, swansea, wales</address>
            <team>ospreys</team>
        </person>
        <person nat=".."> ... </person>
    </group>
    <group name="..."> .... </group>
</list>
```

I need to display the list of names of person using a different color in html (red, blue,etc.) for each nationality. I can't figure out how can i achieve at that purpose.
Here is my attempt:

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <html>
        <body>
           <xsl:for-each-group select="group/person" group-by="@nat">
             <!--<xsl:variable name="color" select="position()"/>-->  
            <b><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>: </b>
               <p> <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/name" separator=", "/></p>
           </xsl:for-each-group>
           
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not well-defined. What color do you want to assign to each nationality? Please edit your question and show the expected result.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i want to use a different color in html like black; green, etc. to show persons based on their nationality.

Comment: This does not answer my question. What logic should the stylesheet use in order to select the color for a nationality? If you have a list of all possible nationalities, then assign a color to each and use the resulting list in your stylesheet. If not, then maybe construct a list of all colors you want to use and select from this list in rotation using `mod`. And you're still not showing how exactly you want to use the selected color.

Comment: Colours for HTML representation are usually set using CSS e.g. inline style `<p style="color: {$colours[$index]}"><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/name" separator=", "/></p>` where you could have a parameter or variable `<xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>` inside of the `for-each-group` and a global parameter or variable with a list of colours bound to the variable `$colours`, that could be read from a separate file or from a string list in XSLT 2.

Comment: @michael.hor257k When a nationality change I have to change the color of text. it doesn't matter what a color i choose for each nationality. each group of persons that belongs to the same nationality must shown with the same color. again it doesn't matter what a color i have to choose for same group.

Answer (score 1):

So you want e.g. `<xsl:param name="colours" as="xs:string*" select="'red', 'blue', 'yellow'"/>` as a global parameter and CSS `<p style="color: {$colours[$index]}"><xsl:value-of select="current-group()/name" separator=", "/></p>` where you have bound `<xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>` inside the `for-each-group`.

Comment: Is there any way that let me makes the list of colors maximum as possible. for exemple i want something like this:  `<p style="color:{$color+ $index}">` where  `$color ` is integer.

Comment: The `$colours` variable binding I have shown as an example lists three colour values, of course you can pass in a much longer list as your needed/wanted parameter. The `$index` is an integer selecting an item from that list. I am not sure what kind of colour value you want to get by adding two integers, CSS also support RGB hex triples though (e.g. `#FF00EE`).